# How to show ErrorIcon in DataGridViewCll on Cell TextChange?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two columns in a `DataGridView`:

- orderdQuantity
- receivedQuantity

If I input receivedQuantity greater than orderdQuantity, then on that cell `TextChanged` event, I want to display ErrorIcon.
Currently, it is not functioning as I previously described. What currently is working is, if I click on another cell of `DataGridview`, then `ErrorIcon` is displayed.

My code is the following:

```
//txtBox_TextChanged is called in datagridview1_EditingControlShowing() event

private void txtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (datagridview1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (txtBox.Text != "")
            {
                int rowIndex = datagridview1.CurrentRow.Index;
                int recQty = Convert.ToInt32(txtBox.Text);
                int orderedQty = Convert.ToInt32(datagridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Ordered Qty"].Value);
                if (recQty > orderedQty)
                {
                    this.datagridview1.CurrentCell.ErrorText = "Invalid Quantity";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Oops something went wrong.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How can I show the error icon when the user is typing in the cell?**

By default when you set `ErrorText` for a cell, the error icon will not show when the cell is in edit mode. Also none of events of the `DataGridView` handles change of text while the user is typing in a cell. 
To set an error text and show error icon while the user is typing in a cell you should follow these steps:

- Get the editing control in `EditingControlShowing` and handle its `TextChanged` event.
- In the `TextChanged` event of the text box, set or remove `ErrorText` for the cell.
- Apply a right padding to the cell when starting edit and in `CellBeginEdit`  event and remove it in `CellEndEdit`.
- Paint error icon in `CellPainting` event.

[image]

**Example**

This example shows an error in cell while the user types in the first cell if the text of the cell become empty.

In `EditingControlShowing` attach `TextChanged` event to the `TextBox`:

```
void grid_EditingControlShowing(object sender,DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.grid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        var textbox = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
        if (textbox != null)
        {
            textbox.TextChanged -= textBox_TextChanged;
            textbox.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
        }
    }
}
```

In `TextChanged` event of `TextBox` perform validation and remove or set `ErrorText` for the cell:

```
void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = (TextBox)sender;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
        this.grid.CurrentCell.ErrorText = "Invalid Value";
    else
        this.grid.CurrentCell.ErrorText = null;
}
```

In `CellBeginEdit` add a right padding to show error Icon and in `CellEndEdit` we remove the padding:

```
void grid_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    cell.Style.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 18, 0);
}
void grid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.RowIndex];
    cell.Style.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

In `CellPainting` draw error icon yourself:

```
private void grid_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All &
                        ~(DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon));
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.ErrorText))
    {
        GraphicsContainer container = e.Graphics.BeginContainer();
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(e.CellStyle.Padding.Right, 0);
        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ErrorIcon);
        e.Graphics.EndContainer(container);
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```