# Handling keyboard events for custom DataGridView column type

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, user-controls, datagridviewtextboxcell

In the code below I'm extending the class DataGridViewTextBoxCell to control the values that the user will input in this field, for that I need to catch the event KeyDown. But the event is invoked only when I'm navigating in the DGV using the keyboard. When I'm editing the value of the cell the event doesn't happen. What is missing in my code?

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();

            MyDataGridViewColumn col = new MyDataGridViewColumn();
            dataGridView.Columns.Add(col);
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(new string[] { "0" });
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(new string[] { "1" });
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(new string[] { "2" });
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(new string[] { "3" });

            this.panel1.Controls.Add(dataGridView);
        }
    }

    public class MyDataGridViewColumn : DataGridViewColumn
    {
        public MyDataGridViewColumn()
        {
            this.CellTemplate = new MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        }
    }

    public class MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    {
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e, int rowIndex)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e, rowIndex);

            var key = e.KeyCode;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to override the [`InitializeEditingControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.initializeeditingcontrol) to subscribe to the cell's `TextBox` events.

Comment: @Dmitry, thank you for the indication, but I don't found how to do that. Do you have some examples that I could see how to do that?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you are trying to check for. Are you wanting to only allow certain keys to be entered into the text box like a number only cell or a decimal only cell? If this is the case, then as others have noted, you want to subscribe to the grids `EditingControlShowing` event. The event fires when  a cell goes into “edit” mode. Then in that event you would cast the cell to a `TextBox` and then subscribe to the `TextBoxes.KeyPress` event. This will work however; the user will still be able to “paste” invalid values into the cell. Therefore more work is needed.

Comment: The following link… [How to enter letters in one column cell of the table and only numbers in the other column cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69660067/how-to-enter-letters-in-one-column-cell-of-the-table-and-only-numbers-in-the-oth) … demonstrates how to do this AND checks for invalid text that may get “pasted” into the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those key strokes will be handled by the editing control. If you want to create your own custom column type for this purpose, then you can to do it like this:

1. Create your editing control by deriving from [DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxeditingcontrol?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Then override `OnKeyDown` and add your logic there.
2. Create your cell by deriving from [MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcell?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Then override [EditType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.edittype?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and return type of the editing control which you created in previous step.
3. Finally, create your column by deriving from [DataGridViewTextBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and in the constructor, set an instance of the cell that you created in the previous step, as its [CellTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

**Example**

```
public class MyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    public MyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    {
        CellTemplate = new MyDataGridCViewTextBoxCell();
    }
}
public class MyDataGridCViewTextBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public override Type EditType => typeof(MyDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl);
}
public class MyDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl : DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        //Put the logic here
    }
}
```

**Note 1:** For cases that you don't need to create a new column type, you can easily handle [EditingControlShowing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event of the `DataGridView` and check if the event belongs to your desired column, then get the editing control (and cast it to the right type), and then handle the proper event of the editing control, for example you can take a look at first code block in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061236/3110834).

**Note 2:** If you are interested to add custom properties to the column/cell and use them in the editing control, you can find a step by step answer including the sample code in this post:

- [Add new property to custom DataGridView Column and use in in the custom EditingControl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70522376/3110834)

Comment: Thank you very much, this example works very well, but now I have another problem that maybe you can help me. In the control MyDataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl, I need to create some properties that I need to set before starting editing the cell. How can I access these properties?

Comment: @DrausioDonini You should usually have the same property in the column, cell and the editing control. The cell also should implement the clone method. Then in InitializeEditingControl, you can set the property value for the editing control and use it.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the post as it is; it's clean, focused and not too long. Try to apply my comment on your code and if you encountered a problem that you couldn't solve, I'd be happy to help, once you ask a new question :)

Comment: The reason that I preferred to keep this answer as it is, is because the focus of the post is on handling keyboard events and adding custom properties is something that suites just your use case. Future readers who just want to handle the key events, they do not need to add any custom property and they may get confused by those properties. Anyhow, I answered your new question and will share a link of the other post here as well.